# How to invoke an Elsa workflow with request body?

Tags: asp.net, .net, elsa-workflows

Been trying to use **Elsa Workflows 2.11** for my Memo Approval System.

```
var workflow = await _workflowRegistry.FindByNameAsync(workflowDefinitionName, VersionOptions.Latest);
await _workflowDispatcher.DispatchAsync(new ExecuteWorkflowDefinitionRequest(workflow!.Id, Input: new WorkflowInput() { Input = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(memoModel) }), CancellationToken.None);
```

I am trying to send my model object memoModel into the workflow. The workflow is being called but faulted with following error in the Journal.

```
{
 "Type": "Elsa.Exceptions.TypeConversionException",
 "Message": "Failed to convert an object of type System.String to Elsa.Activities.Http.Models.HttpRequestModel",
 "StackTrace": "   at Elsa.ObjectConverter.ConvertTo(Object value, Type targetType)\r\n   at Elsa.ObjectConverter.ConvertTo[T](Object value)\r\n   at Elsa.Activities.Http.HttpEndpoint.ExecuteInternal(ActivityExecutionContext context)\r\n   at Elsa.Services.Activity.OnExecuteAsync(ActivityExecutionContext context)\r\n   at Elsa.Services.Workflows.WorkflowRunner.TryExecuteActivityAsync(ActivityOperation activityOperation, ActivityExecutionContext activityExecutionContext, IActivity activity, CancellationToken cancellationToken)",
 "InnerException": {
  "Type": "System.InvalidCastException",
  "Message": "Invalid cast from 'System.String' to 'Elsa.Activities.Http.Models.HttpRequestModel'.",
  "StackTrace": "   at System.Convert.DefaultToType(IConvertible value, Type targetType, IFormatProvider provider)\r\n   at System.String.System.IConvertible.ToType(Type type, IFormatProvider provider)\r\n   at System.Convert.ChangeType(Object value, Type conversionType, IFormatProvider provider)\r\n   at Elsa.ObjectConverter.ConvertTo(Object value, Type targetType)",
  "InnerException": null,
  "Data": {}
 },
 "Data": {}
}
```

The Http Request Activity in the workflow is set as "POST" and set to "Read Content". Is there anything I need to do to accept the request block that I am trying to send? I mean in the Variables part of the workflow.

Comment: Any workaround you found for this?

Comment: Hi @Amateur_coder, I found this github repo and thought it should help you out. Plus point if you know Spanish. :D
https://github.com/lechediaz/learning-elsa